# How to delete record from two or more tables

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have two tables *resume_update* and *wp_rsjp_submissions*

When I do a union of both tables I can fetch the records successfully but delete is not working. I have this query

```
<?php
    include('wp-blog-header.php');

    if($_POST['id']) { 
      $id=$_POST['id'];
      //echo($id); enter code here
      //$sql = "delete from user where id='$id'";`enter code here`global $wpdb;

      $row = $wpdb->get_row("delete from wp_rsjp_submissions, resume_update using wp_rsjp_submissions, resume_update where id='$id'");
    }
?>
```

Comment: You cannot delete from multiple tables this way. Each table requires its own delete query.

Comment: You must be cascade delete on tables then delete parent automatically delete from child

Comment: @JayBlanchard Well he could if he had triggers setup to maintain a relational database structure without unrelated data.

Comment: Please describe in your questions for which CMS, Framework you are doing code. Its useful to all whose want to give answer. Thanks

Comment: But I would have had to guess that @Mark

Answer (score 2):

In the official documentation for `$wpdb` seen [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), you will see that `get_row()` is used to return a row.

> To retrieve an entire row from a query, use get_row.

If you want to delete, you can use `$wpdb->delete()` or `$wpdb->query()`.

Comment: Is this faster approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code instead.

```
<?php
    include('wp-blog-header.php');

    if($_POST['id']) { 
      $id=$_POST['id'];
      //echo($id); enter code here
      //$sql = "delete from user where id='$id'";`enter code here`global $wpdb;
      $sql = $wpdb->prepare("delete from wp_rsjp_submissions, resume_update using wp_rsjp_submissions, resume_update where id=%d" , array($id));

      $return = $wpdb->query($sql);
    }
?>
```

Also be sure to test your sql directly in mysql. I do not think this sql would work anyway.